# How to enter multi-line code in our questions?

Tags: ros, meta, answers.ros.org

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

For me, it seems that the tool for entering code (available on the toolbar above our ros-answer-question editor) only works for one-line code; we have to click the tool again for a new line.

How if we want to enter multi-line code?
Let's say, I want to copy-paste a chunk of code.

What is the trick, guys, please?

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42780/how-to-enter-multi-line-code-in-our-questions?/) by [tor](https://answers.ros.org/users/1552/tor/) on ROS Answers with karma: 277 on 2012-08-31

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Evgeny](https://answers.ros.org/users/149/evgeny/) on 2013-02-23**:
Indent by 4 characters the whole mulitline block of code and it will be highlighted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can first paste the whole (multiline) code snippet, mark it afterwards and then click on the < code > icon. This should have the requested effect.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-08-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dinosaur](https://answers.ros.org/users/21732/dinosaur/) on 2015-06-26**:
I think the editing window has changed. I don't see an < code > icon. Markdown syntax of three backticks before and after the code doesn't seem to work for multiline blocks. What's the right way?

**Comment by [slelievre](https://answers.ros.org/users/26216/slelievre/) on 2016-03-09**:
@dinosaur: the syntax for displaying blocks of code is just to indent by 4 spaces.
Alternatively, select any number of lines and click the < code > button, which is the one with '101 010'.